# StructureMap Dependency Resolution : Manually get instance from ActionFilter

Tags: structuremap, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to follow this tutorial using StructureMap : http://iridescence.no/post/Constructor-Injection-for-ASPNET-MVC-Action-Filters.aspx

What I'm trying to figure out is the StructureMap equivalent of this line:

```
var container = (ICanResolveDependencies) HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
```

I want to get the container back, so I can resolve dependencies there manually.

This is how I am setting the dependencyresolver in global.asax

```
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(
            new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with NHibernate. You should remove that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just require `IContainer` dependency in your action filter's constructor. If it's not registered automatically by `StructureMap`, you could register it with:

```
For<IContainer>().Use<Container>();
```

---

**Edit**

**Option 1:** Couldn't you just use something like:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.GetService(...)
// or (not sure what would be the right syntax)
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.Current.GetService(...)
```

There got to be some way of retrieving the current service resolver once you set it.

**Option 2:** With regular MVC you can get the current resolver like this:

```
DependencyResolver.Current
```

And use it like this:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService()
```

Looks like WebAPI doesn't use DependencyResolver, but according to [this blog post](http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/using-aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-with.html), you could set it like this:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
// this override is needed because WebAPI is not using DependencyResolver to build controllers
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(
    DependencyResolver.Current.GetService,
    DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices);
```

Now try to use `DependencyResolver.Current` from your action filter.

**Option 3:** Use `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` directly - Probably not the best idea in MVC project, since it should already be encapsulated in IDependencyResolver instance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but this is MVC4.  Everything I've looked at says that I need to get fancy if I want to inject into my filters/attributes.  Can you provide a more detailed example?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you are already using constructor injection in your action filter. I have edited the answer. See if anything of these could help.

Comment: You're the man!  I went with option1.  Option2 gets to be a pain because there are 2 identical interfaces for resolvers.